# dynamodb credential works when used directly but fails when going thru kinesis

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, credentials, amazon-kinesis

I have used kinesis in the past and do not remember encountering this problem. I am setting up a kinesis client to read from a stream. The credentials allow me to access S3 and kinesis with no problem. But it throws this exception

```
com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.leases.exceptions.DependencyException: com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException: The security token included in the request is invalid. (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: UnrecognizedClientException
```

the trigger line is

```
at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.leases.impl.LeaseManager.createLeaseTableIfNotExists(LeaseManager.java:118)
```

However, when I use the same credentials in a dynamodb client app, it works perfectly. Why the difference going thru kinesis?

Answer (score 0):

it's a clearn aws sdk bug. by changing ProfileCredentialsProvider to DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain, it all started working.